# Why does Eclipse Java Package Explorer use the System Font?

Tags: eclipse, fonts

There is no way to adjust the font or font size of the Java Package Explorer. It inherits the font settings from the system. In the case of Windows XP, the default 8 point font is too small for my taste. I'd like to enlarge it. When I do that, however, this affects the browser and other applications and in some cases makes the font too large in other contexts (such as Firefox Tab Text).

Comment: In general, Eclipse likes to default to using tiny, completely illegible fonts.  Drives me crazy.  8pt is not a reasonable choice for anything on a screen.

Comment: If you are using Juno, you can adjust that font [by CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15011440/1385678).

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse is supposed to respect the OS settings but it turns out on Mac OS X the default setting for eclipse is to use small Fonts rather than the standard os fonts.

on Mac OS X you can change edit the eclipse.ini file and remove `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts` restart eclipse and presto you will find that your package explorer looks brilliant with reasonable sized fonts.

Comment: Thanks, that helped.  It still wasn't large enough for me, so I set it to largeFonts.