# I cannot change the font size of package explorer in Eclipse

Tags: css, eclipse, e4

I try to change the font size of package explorer in Eclipse from menu *Window* → *Preferences* → *General* → *Appearance*, and I fail to change the font size. How can I do that? I use Eclipse v4.2 (Juno) on Windows 7.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I configure the font size for the tree item in the package explorer in eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124629/how-can-i-configure-the-font-size-for-the-tree-item-in-the-package-explorer-in-e)

Comment: @mohammed: maybe it's time to revisit which one is the correct answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse is using native Windows widgets and their settings can only be changed from Display Properties / Settings / Advanced / General properties tab. There you can change your screen DPI to alter font sizes.

Comment: but I don't want to change my screen DPI

Comment: Hey, you asked how and just gave you solution, don't blame me if you don't want to use it. :)

Comment: Actually, you can override those settings [by CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15011440/1385678).

Answer (score 29):

On Juno and up you can adjust that font by CSS.

Lookup the files in `eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.2.x.y\css` for your current style sheet (probably `e4_default_win7.css`), and then just add the following rule:

```
#org-eclipse-jdt-ui-PackageExplorer Tree,
#org-eclipse-ui-navigator-ProjectExplorer Tree {
  font-size: 10px; /* <-- Desired font size */
}
```

*Update:* stylesheets are in `eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_x.x.x.vxxxxx/css` folder since Eclipse 4.4 (Luna).

Comment: See also [Jeeeyul's Eclipse Themes - Chrome](https://github.com/jeeeyul/eclipse-themes) for an easier way to edit the CSS, and [Themeable RWT Widgets](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.rap.doc%2Fguide%2Freference%2Ftheming%2Findex.html) for some elements to style. Could not find a reference for ids to specific parts though.

Comment: Unfortunately this only affects part of the folders and files. Some are still small. Running Eclipse 4.7.1

Answer (score 20):

FYI:

From Eclipse v4.4 (Luna):

It looks like the CSS files are no longer in the old folder:

```
`eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.x.x.vy/css`,
```

They are moved to the new folder:

`eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_x.x.x.vxxxxx/css`

And you must select a theme to apply it, in the menu *Windows* → *Preference* → *General* → *Appearance*.

Comment: as stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16799846/2757620) if you want to change it on mac add ".MPart Tree{ font-size: 18;}" at the end of the file e4-dark_mac.css for the dark style, at at the end of file e4_default_mac.css for the regular style change.

Answer (score 17):

This worked for me:

```
.MPart Tree{
  font-size: 8;
}
```

Comment: If this entry is missing, you can add it to the e4_basestyle.css

Comment: I added this entry and it is the only solution of all suggested one I found that did actually work for me (Eclipse Mars @ OS X)

Comment: this worked for STS 3.6.3 which is Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.1),  i changed plugins\org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.0.1.v20140819-1717\css\e4_default_win7.css on my win7 desktop.

Comment: It doesn't work for the whole tree for me. It makes some of the entries larger, but I am looking for a different class to make all of the tree nodes larger

Answer (score 7):

These are my settings and a screenshot of the IDE.

```css
    #org-eclipse-jdt-ui-PackageExplorer Tree,
    #org-eclipse-ui-navigator-ProjectExplorer Tree,
    #org-eclipse-ui-views-ContentOutline Tree,
    #PerspectiveSwitcher ToolBar {
      font-size: 8px;
    }

    .MPartStack {
      font-size: 8;
      swt-simple: false;
      swt-mru-visible: false;
    }
```

[image: Eclipse screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

You can lookup the CSS style files in `eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.X.vY/css` edit your current style (probably `e4_default_win7.css`).

Add something like this:

```css
    #org-eclipse-ui-jdt-PackageExplorer {
       font-size: 20pt;
    }
```

and hope you have a nice and large font (I did not check it myself).

Pro tip: Next time you need to find the CSS Id for a part of the UI, use *CSS Spy* which you can open with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd> (after you have installed it).

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me using version 2019-09 on Windows 10:

- Locate the directory `C:\Users\johndoe\.p2\pool\plugins` in File Explorer, replacing  *"johndoe"* with your own Windows user ID.
- Depending on what you have done in the past with Eclipse, you should see one or more directories with names that start with `org.eclipse.ui.themes`.
- Select the one with the most recent date modified. In my case its name was `org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.700.v20190826-0816`.
- Within that directory open the directory named `css`.
- Open the file named **e4_default_win.css** in a text editor, and append something similar to the following at the end of the file:

> Tree {
>       font-size: 24px;
>       font: Mistral; }

- Don't pick those specific values! You should pick the font and font size you want. I deliberately made poor choices only to make the effect of those settings obvious in the screen shot below.
- Save the file and restart Eclipse. You should see that the font has been changed in the Project Explorer and Package Explorer views, and a lot of other places as well:

  [image: screenShotWithNewFont]
- Just be clear, the name of the file I edited was    `C:\Users\johndoe\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.700.v20190826-0816\css\e4_default_win.css`. The name of the file you edit won't be exactly that, but it should be similar.

Answer (score 2):

On [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr) this was the best choice for me:

```
.MPart Tree{
  font-size: 10;
}
```

Comment: I think it looks best in Ubuntu with `font-size:8px` and `font-family: Sans;`

Comment: Yes, sure. In my case i wanted i little bit bigger but this was my personal preference.

Comment: This works on windows too - just make sure you're editing the right theme file.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I'm using **DevStyle** plugin with Spring Tool Suite 4.

The font size of project explorer can be changed going to Eclipse menu bar:

- Window

  - Preferences

    - DevStyle

      - Extras

        - **Explorer font size**

---

[image: Eclipse Preferences]

This setting is saved into workspace folder:

```
\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\com.genuitec.eclipse.ui.common.platform\extra-styling.css
```

> I tried edit directly in file but when open Eclipse the file was **overwritten**

> Using [STS 4.8.0.RELEASE](https://spring.io/blog/2020/09/16/spring-tools-4-8-0-released) based on `Eclipse 2020-09` (requires a `JDK11`)

Answer (score 2):

Finally, from Eclipse 2020-09 (4.17) there is an option "Tree and Table font view" in `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts` which changes size of the font in Package Explorer, among others.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as of 2021, no need to alter css anymore.

Answer (score 2):

If it helps you to spot the setting easier , this is a screenshot how to change the font elsewhere than the font from the editor window

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Veger's reply, I successfully changed the font of my PHP Explorer in PHP Perspective (with PDT installed). The following CSS code,

```css
    #org-eclipse-php-ui-explorer Tree {
       font-family: Consolas;
       font-size: 21px;
    }
```

are added into my "eclipse-4.3\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.3.1.v20130911-1000\css\e4_default_win7.css" file.

You may choose a different CSS file, depending on the theme you choose through *Preferences* → *General* → *Appearance*: "Theme" drop-down list).

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse 4.7.x the CSS files are under eclipse⁩/⁨plugins⁩/⁨org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.1.v20170809-1435⁩/⁨css⁩/

In my case I use the dark theme for OSX, so I opened the file e4-dark_mac.css and added the font-size line:

```
CTabFolder Tree, CTabFolder Canvas {
    background-color: #2F2F2F;
    color: #CCC;
    font-size: 13pt; // new 
}
```