# Mac os X Eclipse Package Explorer view , project folders in smaller size

Tags: eclipse, macos

I recently brought Mac Book Pro and I installed Eclipse Luna. I am facing a problem in viewing the Java projects in "Package Explorer" folders are very small. Is there a way to increase instead of changing the screen resolution?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529727/i-cannot-change-the-font-size-of-package-explorer-eclipse/15011440#15011440

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible, have a look at this link: http://blog.vogella.com/2013/02/19/css-styling-individual-part-of-the-eclipse-ide/

(Copy of the essential part, in case the above link stops working:

```
#org-eclipse-jdt-ui-PackageExplorer {
      font-size:20;
      background:black;
}
```

)

Remains the question, where to put those lines. Best would be to create your own style, but I never figured out how to do it. So I usually just modify one of the built-in styles. To do this, go to `/Applications/eclipse4.4/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.0.1.v20140819-1717/css` and open the css-file of the style you currently use (probably `e4_default_mac.css`). Then add the above lines at the end of that css file and restart Eclipse. Note: when updating Eclipse, you might have to repeat those steps.

EDIT: Just realized it was already asked and answered on SO: [I cannot change the font size of package explorer in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529727/i-cannot-change-the-font-size-of-package-explorer-eclipse/15011440#15011440)  Don't look at the accepted answer, but at the next one below.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to change the size of folders or other visual properties of package explorer.

The views, fonts, etc... of general views are set by the system/OS properties. Only the editor view allows customization of sizing, such as, font.