# Eclipse luna mac osx package explorer tree view

Tags: eclipse, macos, egit

I have updated package explorer font size by as per the answer in the post
[Mac os X Eclipse Package Explorer view , project folders in smaller size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27273349/mac-os-x-eclipse-package-explorer-view-project-folders-in-smaller-size?noredirect=1#comment43018672_27273349) in mac theme CSS and it works well. But when I update a java or properties file, it font size is reset to the default(I am unable to find what is the default size). I enabled Maven and Git for my project, how to retain the same font size even after updating the files.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration is present in eclipse>preferences>change colors and fonts > Git > Uncommitted Change Font.