# Eclipse RCP: How can I bold a folder in Project Explorer?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, project-explorer

How can I (programmatically) bold a folder\file in Project Explorer in Eclipse?

Just like Visual Studio, which bolds the start-up project:

[image: VS: The start-up project is bold]

Comment: What's the boldness signify?

Comment: @nitind - I have some files, each holding other build settings, and the user may choose (in a dialog) the one he wants. I want to bold the wanted file, so it will be clear what the current settings are.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Resource Decorator Plug-in](http://codeandme.blogspot.in/p/blog-page_7.html). You can control the foreground and background color of resources but cannot make them **bold**.

Also Check these posts [How can I configure the font size for the tree item in the package explorer in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124629/how-can-i-configure-the-font-size-for-the-tree-item-in-the-package-explorer-in-e) and [I cannot change the font size of package explorer in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529727/i-cannot-change-the-font-size-of-package-explorer-eclipse) choose whichever solution you need.