# Is it possible to make project name bold in the project explorer?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a use case that i have to make one project name bold out of 2 project name in the project explorer like below.

**Project1**

Project2

Please let me know for any idea.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: May be this can help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36996554/eclipse-rcp-how-can-i-bold-a-folder-in-project-explorer

Comment: You could rename `Project1` to `` (or `1`,  ``, `1`, or `➀`)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [decorator extension point](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Decorators/decorators.html)

```
<extension
       point="org.eclipse.ui.decorators">
    <decorator
        lightweight="true"
        label="Label Decorator"
        class="yourPackage.BoldDecorator"
        state="true"
        id="your.decorator.id">
     <description>
        Some description
     </description>
  </decorator>
</extension>
```

and implement a [`ILightweightLabelDecorator`](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ILightweightLabelDecorator.html)

```
public class BoldDecorator implements ILightweightLabelDecorator {

    @Override
    public void decorate(Object element, IDecoration decoration) {
        Font boldFont = JFaceResources.getFontRegistry()
                              .getBold(JFaceResources.DEFAULT_FONT);
        decoration.setFont(boldFont);
    }

    @Override
    public void addListener(ILabelProviderListener listener) {
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLabelProperty(Object element, String property) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void removeListener(ILabelProviderListener listener) {
    }
}
```

The result will be

[image: BoldDecorator]

Answer (score -1):

> Is it possible to make project name bold in the project explorer?

Yes, but this is not standard behaviour; you must write a plug-in which does that.